# ruby on rails join conditions (with squeel)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord, squeel

I'm trying to use Squeel to compare attributes among the joined tables along with a little math.

Here's an example of the query:

```
Parent.joins{[child1, child2.grandchildren]}.
where{grandchildren.birth_datetime > Time.now - child1.age.years}
```

I get an error from Squeel saying "TypeError: can't convert Squeel::Nodes::KeyPath into an exact number"

Anyone know what I'm doing wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

Does

```
Parent.
  joins{[child1, child2.grandchildren]}.
  where{child2.grandchildren.birth_datetime > (Time.current - child1.age.years)}
```

do the trick?